# How to specify maxExclusive on struct?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, struct, gpx

I want to create a structure `Degrees` for a [GPX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_eXchange_Format) library. In the [XSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) for GPX ([GPX 1.1 Schema](http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd)) `degreesType` is defined as minInclusive = 0 and maxExclusive = 360. The structure now shall have two public static fields `MinValue = 0` and `MaxValue = x`:

```
public struct Degrees : IFormattable, IComparable, IComparable<Degrees>, IEquatable<Degrees>
{
    private decimal value;

    public static Degrees MinValue = 0M;
    //public static Degrees MaxValue = x;
}
```

What is the best way to specify the value of x? 360D-1 would be to inaccurate, 360D-0.001 would be an assumption that no one ever wants a better accuracy than 1/1000 degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two approaches:

- Have your struct faithfully represent
  the fact that the range is specified
  with an inclusive minimum and an
  exclusive maximum; ie, give your
  struct `MinInclusive` and `MaxExclusive`
  members. This might be regarded as
  teaching your struct too much about
  the implementation detail of the XSD,
  though
- Define `MaxValue` as the highest representable `decimal` value less than 360. Since `decimal` is a decimal floating point type, we have to be a little careful here, but I *think* I'm right in saying that since the smallest possible value is `10^-28`, and with 360 we have two powers of ten to the left of the decimal point, the relevant value is `360 - 10^-26`, or

  ```
  const decimal MaxValue = 359.99999999999999999999999999m;
  ```

  I assume you're taking care of the conversion from `decimal` to `Degree`. Note that the type declaration character for `decimal` is `m` or `M` - `d` or `D` is for `double`.

Comment: Yes, I knew about (and used) the M/m literal, until I was irritated today by the following sentence in the MSDN Library under the topic "D literal type character": Appending the literal type character D to a literal forces it to the Decimal data type. Appending the identifier type character @ to any identifier forces it to Decimal.

Nevertheless I'm taking care of all conversions that have to take place. For the reason of clarity I did not include the whole structure definition.

Comment: That page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33.aspx I guess) is about VB.net ...